# Does the Apple Remote (Aluminium) with IR still have a use?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, appletv, remote-control

I'm wondering if I can *still use the old Apple Remote ([Aluminium](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/ht200131)) with IR to control some Apple devices*?
I have the Retina MacBook (without IR)(how?), an iPhone and an Apple TV. Perhaps it can also pair with *other (non-Apple) products*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background**
The Retina MacBook Pro does not have an IR sensor, just like the missing battery indicator. Apple really pushed hard to feature more Bluetooth heavy peripherals from that point. Looking back it seems like the right step forward. The Siri remote (just as an example) is able to transmit more complex data than the older, yet well-built aluminum IR remote ever could. The IR sensor has become obsolete because of features such as AirPlay and other mechanisms that put increasingly growing control into one place (the iOS device).

**What can you try?**

- You may be able to pair the Apple Remote with your Apple TV if you
  happen to have one that was released around the same time. [This
  tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfNMd0T8cqc) should demonstrate how the Aluminum remote can be paired
  with an Apple TV (2<sup>nd</sup> generation).   I have to be honest
  in that I don't personally own an Apple TV or the remote for that
  matter, yet at work, we have seamlessly paired various different
  remotes (from different 2<sup>nd</sup> or 3<sup>rd</sup> generation
  Apple TVs).
- You will however not be able to pair the remote with the iPhone because much like the Mac, the iPhone does not have an IR sensor.
- I fail to come up with everyday things that have an IR sensor capable of receiving signals from the Apple Remote but are non-Apple products. Correct me if I am wrong but I don't think that there are any devices worth controlling, let alone capable of receiving the signal. Yep, that's Apple for you.

Let me know if that was helpful in any way or if you come up with other ideas/products.

Comment: yeah, i know i will receive an advice like this, i just had a little hope that maybe i can reuse it with other products. I saw on te internet that maybe buying and pairing with an usb IR receiver, the remote could work. But again, apple making ephimeral products.Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of third-party IR receivers that can plug into a modern Apple product via USB and (supposedly) will allow you to use your old-style infrared Apple Remote with a newer computer.  For example, [this website](https://gusdevices.wixsite.com/devices-english/about) purports to sell IR receivers with either USB-A or USB-C connectivity.  A [similar product is sold on Amazon here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBRBWS6).  Finally, [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXUt_SC1Vtw) tells you how to make your own version.  (Disclaimer: I have not tested any of these products or methods and can't confirm whether they actually work.)